# laravel middleware redirection when new user logged in

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, middleware

I want to redirect to a new page when a user logged in first time.Otherwise the user is going to the correct path.The issue is that when i redirect the route to sign_up process the route called and it again send me to the same middleware so there is a kind of loop has been generated.Please tell me how to handle it.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TutorMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard=null)
    {
        if (\Auth::guard($guard)->check() && \Auth::user()->type == '3'){
          //  if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
           //     return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
          //     } 
            // else { return redirect()->guest('/home'); 
          if(\Auth::user()->first_time_login==false){
            // redirecting infinitely  
            // there must be a condition that check if i am not in the tutor.signup_process route
            return redirect()->route('tutor.signup_process');
          }      
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->guest('/login/join_as_a_tutor');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to prevent access to all other routes before the task in the redirected page has been completed?

Comment: yes, if a user logged in first time then he should be redirected to signup_process page otherwise he should go to profile page which is working properly.if he is not signedin then he should go to login page

Comment: if you do not use this middleware for the route that is being redirected to then your issue might be fixed. Since we will not be checking if the user is first time logged in or not for that specific route so you can break away from the loop

Comment: i can also use controller to check and redirect from there.Should i use controller intead of middleware to do this task

Comment: Another thing is Request not working in middleware?

Comment: If this check is only done for the first user logged in the system and also the user can access other routes without completing the task in the redirected route. Then Middleware is not necessary. You can perform this in LoginController. 

Request works in middleware too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, this is how:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->tutor = \Auth::user();

        if ($this->tutor->first_time_login == true && !\Request::is('tutor/signup_process')) {
            return redirect()->route('tutor.signup_process');
        }

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```